# bool and unsigned index argument vs signed index argument

Tags: c++

This is very subjective question. I'm trying to write a logic "set null or use index argument". And I came up with the idea of additional bool argument or using negative index argument for set null condition. I wonder which one would be better.

For example, if there is a class member function as below,

```
bool DoSomething(bool bSetNull, unsigned int unIndex)
{
    bool bReturn = false;
    if (bSetNull)
    {
        m_pObject = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        m_pObject = m_pArr[unIndex]; // m_pArr could be replaced by something like m_map.find(unIndex)
        bReturn = true;
    }
    return bReturn;
}
```

vs.

```
bool DoSomething(int nIndex)
{
    bool bReturn = false;
    if (nIndex < 0)
    {
        m_pObject = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        m_pObject = m_pArr[unIndex]; // m_pArr could be replaced by something like m_map.find(unIndex)
        bReturn = true;
    }
    return bReturn;
}
```

Actually, the former is bothering due to additional bool argument and the latter is bothering due to use of signed type of index argument.
Please give me advice if there is better option.

Comment: You seem to be looking for [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: When you set `m_pObject` to `nullptr`, it should be called `clear()` or `wipe()` instead of `DoSomething()`. It seems `DoSomething()` never use `bSetNull` and `index` at the same time. Separate them into two apis should be reasonable.

Comment: @273K Oh thanks what a new feature I didn't know

Comment: @Louis Go Thanks for comment. Oh actually DoSomething() does more stuff afterward with m_pObject and other member data. But yeah. Perhaps my actual api is trying to do too many things.

Comment: Change the current `DoSomething()` to private method, and add 2 methods just call it.

Comment: An alternative design is using some large value as an indicator instead of a negative value, like `constexpr unsigned set_null = -1; void DoSomething(unsigned unIndex) { if (unIndex == set_null) { m_pObject = nullptr; } else { m_pObject = m_pArr[unIndex]; } }`. Is there any reason this has to be one function? Two different functions (perhaps with the same name like `void DoSomething()` and `void DoSomething(unsigned unIndex)`, but two different names might be more appropriate) seems better if one of the arguments is going to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In standard C there are some examples of the signed int usage like `int snprintf` return the length or a negative error code.

Because of the long history of C this is not a qualitative argument, but this option will not come as surprise.

However better use an `std::optional` field (for instance) and two functions with and without index. That is not tweaking semantics: the meaning of things.